# How to register ThreadLocalTargetSource without @Primary annotation on ProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

In my application, I'm following this [tutorial](https://tech.asimio.net/2017/11/28/An-alternative-to-ThreadLocal-using-Spring.html) to implement Audit feature using  `ThreadLocalTargetSource`.

One thing that bugs me is that to register the `ThreadLocalTargetSource`, I have to create another `ProxyFactoryBean` with `@Primary` on it as following.

```
@Bean(destroyMethod="destroy")
public ThreadLocalTargetSource threadLocalAuditLog() {
    ThreadLocalTargetSource result = new ThreadLocalTargetSource();
    result.setTargetBeanName("auditLog");

    return result;
}

@Primary
@Bean("proxiedThreadLocalAuditLog")
public ProxyFactoryBean proxiedThreadLocalAuditLog(ThreadLocalTargetSource threadLocalAuditLog) {
    ProxyFactoryBean result = new ProxyFactoryBean();
    result.setTargetSource(threadLocalAuditLog);

    return result;
}
```

I tried to remove `@Primary` and the solution doesn't work anymore. This is supposed to be a common code in all of my projects. Hence, I'd like to avoid the `@Primary` if possible.

As I don't have sufficient knowledge about how the ProxyFactoryBean works, I'd be very grateful if you could explain to me why `@Primary` is a must here. It's great if you could show me how I can achieve the same result without the `@Primary` as well.

Comment: Judging from the tutorial you should rather be using a `request` scope instead of hacking around with this solution or register the `thread` scope and make it `scope` thread. That way you don't need the `ThreadLocalTargetSource` nor the `ProxyFactoryBean`. Can you do without the `@Primary`, in this case no uyou cannot as you have 2 beans of the same type and it needs to know which one to use.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Regarding the 1st point, I did use `@RequestScope` originally to implement my Audit feature. However, I have another feature which requires `@Async`. If I switch from `@RequestScope` to `ThreadLocalTargetSource`, my Audit feature will work as is :).

Comment: @M.Deinum: Regarding the 2nd point, do you mind elaborating a bit on which 2 beans are of the same type? My concern is that if I happen to use `ProxyFactoryBean` elsewhere in my application later on, it will not work. However, I'm not seeing any other `ProxyFactoryBean` in my code.

Comment: The `ProxyFactoryBean` creates a bean of type `AuditLog` (or whatever the type of your bean named `auditLog` is). So is more or less a `ProxyFactoryBean<AuditLog>` and as it is a `FactoryBean` is handled specially. The result is that you have 2 beans of type `AuditLog` and you need to specify which one is the primary one to use (else you will get erros stating that there are 2 beans matching an injection point where 1 was expected). It is a lot easier to register the `SimpleThreadScope` and use `@Scope("thread")` instead of this.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I didn't even know `SimpleThreadScope` exists :). However, from the documentation, it mentions `Note that the SimpleThreadScope does not clean up any objects associated with it.`. On the other hand, from what I read, `ThreadLocalTargetSource` will clean up all resources associated with it upon `destroy()` being called. I'm not sure if this is a valid concern. Perhaps, you can enlighten me a bit further? :D

Comment: The destroy method is only called upon shutdown of your application, not on the end of a thread, next to that a request handling thread isn't ended nor a thread used from a pool. Basically thread-scope and `ThreadLocalTargetSource` suffer the same issue.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks a lot for the pointers :). I will read more on `SimpleThreadScope`.